# Async / Await: Cannot access variable before initialization (javscript)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

When I run the code below I get the following error:

> `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'bar' before initialization`.

Could someone help me understand why this is happening? As far as I can tell, the `foo` function should wait until the promise resolves (since I'm using `await` before moving onto the `console.log(bar)` line. What am I missing here?

```js
function qux() {
  return Math.random();
}

async function bar() {
  let result = await qux();
  return result > 0.5;
}

async function foo() {
  let bar = await bar();
  console.log(bar);
}

foo();
```

Comment: Why are you awaiting qux? It doesn't return a promise.

Comment: The use of `async` and `await` here is incongruous when all you have is synchronous code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is in the function `foo()`

`bar` is already a function and you're trying to assign to it while calling it, which probably isn't what you meant to do.

Change the name of one of them.

```js
function qux() {
  return Math.random();
}

async function bar() {
  let result = await qux();
  return result > 0.5;
}

async function foo() {
  let x = await bar();
  console.log(x);
}

foo();
```

Comment: Ahh, yep you're right — thanks!